# Find completeness of a local ring.

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, metric-spaces

I am studying the book of Commutative Algebra written by Balwant Singh. In the chapter of filtration and completion one exercise says: If $A$ is a complete local ring, $I$ is a proper ideal. Then $A/I$ is a complete local ring.

My question is:

1. Are we supposed to show that if $A$ is $m$-adically complete then $A/I$ is $m/I$-adically complete?
2. How to proceed for this problem?
   I was trying to show that the induced filtration of $A/I$ will be separated, i.e., $\cap (m/I) ^n=0$.As the first step and then I would try to show every cauchy sequence is convergent but I'm stuck.
   Any help will be appreciated.
   Thanks.

Comment: For part (1): yes. (Equivalently, show that $A/I$ is complete as $A$-module ... this is equivalent to showing $A/I$ is complete as a ring since the fundamental system of $\mathfrak m$-adic n.b.d. s are the same whether you consider $A/I$ as $A$-module or as a ring)

Comment: For part (2), as you say, you have first shown the $\mathfrak m$-adic topology on $A/I$ is separated, so the canonical map $A/I \to \widehat {A/I}$ is injective. Now to see surjectivity , first recall (e.g. Proposition 10.13, Atiyah-Macdonald) that $\hat A \otimes_A M \to \hat M$ is Surjective whenever $M$ is f.g. module and if $A$ is complete, then $ \hat A \otimes_A M$ is just $M$ ... now apply this to $M=A/I$ in your case .

Comment: The separated part I couldn't show

Comment: Hmmm ... now that I think about it, I also can't see why it should be separated ... of-course it is true if $A$ is Noetherian (by Krull-intersection), but otherwise, I'm not sure ...